# Adjusting light source size

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am currently trying to position a light starting from the bottom left of my screen and illuminating towards the center of my screen but my light source does not appear circular (light does not seem to be coming from a single point).
[image]

After moving the light source it shines on the entire object but the desired effect is for the lightsource to only shine (based on a point) towards the right.

[image]

```
void init()
{
    camPos[0]= -(size/2)*.1;
    camPos[1]= size*.1;
    camPos[2]= -(size/2)*.1;
    zoom = size/10;
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Enable backface culling
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);  

    //Enable Lighting
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    light_pos[0] = 1;
    light_pos[1] = 10;
    light_pos[2] = 1;
    light_pos[3] = 1;

    gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 100);

};

void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //Camera
    radians =  float(pi*(angle-90.0f)/180.0f);
    //initialize look
    look[0] = (size/2)*.1;
    look[1] = 1;
    look[2] = (size/2)*.1;

    camPos[0] = look[0] + sin(radians)*zoom;
    camPos[1] = size/10;
    camPos[2] = look[2] + cos(radians)*zoom;

    gluLookAt(camPos[0], camPos[1], camPos[2], look[0],look[1],look[2], 0,1,0);
    //lighting
    //glColor3f(1,1,1);


    float m_amb[] = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
    float m_dif[] = {1, 1, 1, 1.0};
    float m_spec[] = {1, 1, 1, 1.0};
    float shiny = 27;

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, m_amb);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, m_dif);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, m_spec);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, shiny);


    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_pos);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    drawTerrain(terrainA, size);
    glutSwapBuffers();

};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    //When program starts enter value

    printf("Enter an int between 50 and 300: ");
    scanf("%i",&size);

    if ( size < 50 || size > 300){
        printf("Invalid size! Please re-run \n");
        return 0;
    }
    populateArray();
    //Starts glut
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    //Init display
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(600, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Terrain");glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    //Registering Callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(special);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    init();

    glutMainLoop(); 


    return 0;
};
```

Comment: It would help people a lot if you post your code.

Comment: @KLibby sorry about that

Comment: You light position doesn't seems right. Last value must be 1 for point light and 0 for directional. Try something like (10,1,10,1) or (10,1,10,1).

Comment: @Michael I tried it but doesn't seem to change anything. I read that it would be directional light as long as it != 0. Is there any way I can specify the size of the light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general practic is to define light attenuation factors as a coeficients of light equation.

[image]

```
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.5);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.5);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 0.2);
```

where `kc` is constant attenuation factor, `kl` - linear attenuation factor, `kq` - quadratic attenuation factor, `d` - distance to light source. You can modify this coeficients to achive the effect you want.

This example could not works correctly so I suggest to build your own light destribution function using shaders, it will be simple to achive desired effect and more effective (and will always work).

Comment: Thanks for your help this is what I was looking for.